# ES6 react js constructor function should work as previous componentWillMount but it doesnt

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this component which should get some state onLoad with ajax.
Basic syntax:

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './Header';
import FeedOwnerColumn from './FeedOwnerColumn';
import FeedColumnRight from './FeedColumnRight';
import ReportBug from './ReportBug';

class FeedApp extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super();

    this.addComment = this.addComment.bind(this);

    var that = this;
    $.ajax({
      url: '/api/getUserInit',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {},
      success: function(response){
        console.log('Success: ', response);
        that.state = {
          ownerInfo: response.ownerInfo,
          ownerDogs: response.ownerDogs,
          ownerNotifications: response.ownerNotifications,
          ownerChat: response.ownerChat,
          posts: response.posts
        };
      },
      error: function(response){
        console.log('Error: ', response);
      }
    });
  }
  addComment(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //console.log(e.target.childNodes[0].value);

    var currTime = new Date();
    currTime = currTime.toLocaleString();

    var commentContent = e.target.childNodes[0].value;

    var key = Math.random();
    key = Math.round(key);

    var newComment = {
      id: key,
      name: "Peter Paprika",
      date: currTime,
      thumb_picture:"/imgs/user-q.jpg",
      profile_link: "/user/123",
      content: commentContent,
      like_amount: 0
    };

    //console.log(this.state.posts);

    var postsObj = this.state.posts;

    //console.log(postsObj[0].comments);

    var newComments = postsObj[0].comments;
    newComments.push(newComment);

    console.log(newComments);
    this.setState({posts: postsObj});

  }
  render() {
    return (
        <div className="clearfix wrapper">
          <Header />
          <FeedOwnerColumn />
          <FeedColumnRight posts={this.state.posts} addComment={this.addComment} />
          <ReportBug />
        </div>
    );
  }
}


export default FeedApp;
```

Unfortunately this method doesn't provide the componentWillMount features since the error I keep receiving with `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'posts' of null"` determines that the state has not been filled yet since the posts state is needed for a map function.

Any Ideas ?

**NOTE**

When I use the componentWillMount Method then I receive the following Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null
```

The Object should be correct I tested it out as static state previously

Comment: Have you tried to set your state in _componentWillMount_ method? [Link](http://egorsmirnov.me/2015/06/14/react-and-es6-part2.html)

Comment: Yep, then I get the following Error:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null

Comment: You explicitly have to initialize the state in the constructor: `this.state = {posts: []};`

Comment: so i have to create it as blank "template" state and then fill in the data in the willmount method?

Comment: I tried it out, now the error is gone but componentWillMount doesnt update the state :/